# Не записывает в массив

Tags: c++, массивы, radstudio

Здравствуйте, не хочет записывать в массив. Программа зависает и не отвечает

```
double h=0.0, tau=0.0, a = 4.0, pi = 3.14;
int n=0, m=0;
do
{
cout << "Enter h: ";
cin >> h;
cout << "Enter tau: ";
cin >> tau;
if (((pow(a,2)*pow(tau,2))/pow(h,2))<1.0)
{
  break;
}
else
{
  cout << "Enter h and tau again\n";
  cout << "result = " << (pow(a,2)*pow(tau,2))/pow(h,2);
}
}
while(1);
n = (pi/h);
m = (pi/tau)+1;
cout << n <<" " << m;

double **matrix = new double *[m];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
  matrix[m] = new double [n];
}

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
  {
    matrix[m][n] = 0;
  } 
    }
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
  cout << endl;
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
  {
    cout << matrix[m][n] << " ";
  }
}


double tmp = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  /// Вот тут зависает
{
    matrix[0][n] = tmp;
    tmp += h;
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout << matrix[0][n] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код, и укажите где зависает

Comment: Укажи где и на каких входных данных.
И почему нельзя решить проблему простой отладкой?

Comment: В теме указал где проблема

Comment: @iksuy Я пытался, но не выходит. Не могу понять причину

Comment: У Вас цикл while бесконечный.
В массив у Вас заносится в 1 елемент массива, 2-строка после вашего коммента `matrix[0][n] = tmp;`, попробуйте посмотреть значение `n` в этом цикле `for`. Если уж отладкой не можете пользоваться сделайте обычный вывод в консоль информации о значении `i` и `n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас все циклы неверные

Например, в этом цикле

```
double **matrix = new double *[m];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
  matrix[m] = new double [n];
}
```

вместо

```
matrix[m] = new double [n];
```

должнобыть

```
matrix[i] = new double [n];
```

Вэтом цикле

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
  {
    matrix[m][n] = 0;
  } 
    }
```

вместо

```
matrix[m][n] = 0;
```

должно быть

```
matrix[i][j] = 0;
```

Аналогично в этом цикле

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
  cout << endl;
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
  {
    cout << matrix[m][n] << " ";
  }
}
```

вместо

```
cout << matrix[m][n] << " ";
```

должно быть

```
cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
```

И в этих двух циклах

```
double tmp = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  /// Вот тут зависает
{
    matrix[0][n] = tmp;
    tmp += h;
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout << matrix[0][n] << " ";
}
```

вместо выражения

```
matrix[0][n]
```

должно быть

```
matrix[0][i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Почему-то мне кажется что вместо

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  /// Вот тут зависает
{
    matrix[0][n] = tmp;
   tmp += h;
}
```

надо писать

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  /// Вот тут зависает
{
    matrix[0][i] = tmp;
   tmp += h;
}
```

а то в цикле смысла не вижу